# A linear topological space over real number field is locally compact ???

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, locally-compact-groups

Let $V$ be a topological $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with ${\rm dim}(V) < \infty$
Then, $V$ is locally compact $??$

Answer (score 1):

A standard theorem in topological vector spaces (over the reals) says that if $n = \dim(V) < \infty$ then $V \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$, so in particular it is locally compact. This is non-trivial, and the converse also holds: if the dimension is not finite, then $V$ is not locally compact.

E.g. See theorems 1.20 and 1.21 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*.
Or pages 244-245 of Dunford and Schwartz *Linear Operators Part I, General Theory*. To name the first two books on functional analysis on my shelf I tried. It's in most standard texts.

Comment: Are there references which contain the theorem and its proof ??

Comment: @神宮寺春姫 any good book on functional analysis? Use Google?

Comment: ok. I try to find it by google.